# iOS3 and iOS4 CoreLocation Permission Dialog

Tags: ios, core-location

When is the location permission dialog shown?

I could test it on a iOS4 device (not in iOS3 :P) and the its shown once. If my app requires of location services it needs to be enabled through `Preferences`.

What about iOS3? If the user denies the location permission, how can the location get enabled por my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The permission dialog is shown the first time that your app attempts to use location.

I'm fairly certain (although not 100% verified) that iOS 3 had some sort of location permission setting, but it was less obvious. I do not think that saying "no" was irreversible.